# Getting frequency for whitespace preserved word in SOLR spell suggestion

Tags: solr, spell-checking, search-suggestion

I am currently working with SOLR spellcheck feature. I am faced with a problem of not able to find the original frequency for the input when it has whitespaces.

For example,

`spellcheck.q=aple` returns me origFreq for the word 'aple'

[image]

However, when I input a text with spaces like `bank of amarica`, I am not getting the frequency of the whole word. Instead it is giving individual word's frequency. The suggestion for this is given via the collation in solr.

[image]

Is there a way to get the `hits` of the input entered with spaces, in this case `bank of amarica`?

Comment: I'm assuming you your configuration of your spellchecker is also handling the search request(I see your empty docs array in the top of the second screenshot). Isn't the numFound part in the response of your query the number you are looking for?

Comment: Would you post more of your configuration? From your solrconfig.xml the `searchComponent` and the `requestHandler` and the relevant part of your schema.xml.

Answer (score 0):

SOLR handles multiple words a bit differently entirely depending on the setting of `sp.query.extendedResults`. If it's `false` then words with spaces are treated as a single token. If it's `true` then they are tokenized and treated as separate words. So try changing the core configuration. If this is not the case, post your config file.